# Why do my [shortcodes] show as plain text from the WP editor?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use shortcodes to execute tag-specific content loops on different pages of my website. I know my shortcode function is working properly, because when I hardcode `do_shortcode` into my page template, it shows up perfectly.

But when I try to add a `[shortcode]` directly into the Wordpress editor instead, it shows as plain text. Any ideas how I can fix this?

You can see what I'm talking about [here](http://phpstack-77308-296444.cloudwaysapps.com/gang/seefour/) - the `[showtag tag="seefour"]` you see as plain text is written directly into the Wordpress text editor. It's not working correctly. Just below it, you'll see the `<?php echo do_shortcode("[showtag tag='seefour']"); ?>` properly executing my content loop from the page template.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Hardcoding `do_shortcode` is not sustainable for me. The site currently only has two active plugins, but this problem persists after deactivating them, so I'm at a loss.

For good measure, this is the content loop I'm trying to execute:

```
function showtag_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'tag' => '', // Default value.
    ), $atts );

    $posts = get_posts( 'tag=' . $atts['tag'] );
    if ( $posts ) {
      $output .= '<div class="jd-container">';
      $output .= '<section class="jd-grid jd-pad1">';
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            $output .= '<div class="jd-box">';
            $output .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink( $post ) . '">';
            $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post );
            $output .= '<div class="jd-overlay"></div>';
            $output .= '<div class="jd-overlay-text">';
            $output .= get_the_title( $post );
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '</a>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }
      $output .= '</section>';
      $output .= '</div>';
    } else {
        $output = 'no data';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'showtag', 'showtag_shortcode' );
```

And here's my **page.php** template code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="jd-backdrop">
  <div class="jd-trans-row jd-container">
    <h2 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <br>
    <p class=""><?= get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID) ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php echo do_shortcode("[showtag tag='seefour']"); ?>
</section>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

None of the solutions I've found so far have worked, so I'm open to suggestions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your theme does not execute do_shortcode() with the content of the post.

Try to add the following to functions.php

```
function the_content_filter( $content) {
    return do_shortcode( $content);
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_filter', 1000);
```

**UPDATE**

From the code of your theme we can see that you use get_post_field to output content of the post. Unlike to the_content(), this function does not invoke any filters. That is why code above does not work in your case.

You have to use get_post_field() in the following manner:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID ) ); ?>
```

P. S. You should also avoid to use <= as it doesn't work on most hostings and is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you for following me here. I didn't want to bog the original question down once you solved the original problem, hence the new question on this page. I've added your new code to functions.php but unfortunately no luck. I sincerely appreciate you continuing to help a novice like me - any other ideas?

Comment: Could you show the php code of the template in your theme which outputs the page? How do you output content of the page?

Comment: No problem - see above. I added it just before the end of the question.

Comment: Awesome. It works. You've been a really big help and I appreciate it. Do I still need your code above in my functions.php file? It doesn't seem so, it seems to work with this newest fix alone, so if we don't need the code above, please edit your answer and I'll check it correct :)

Comment: I have updated the answer. In general case, add_filter can solve the problem, that is why I left it. In your case, you do not need add_filter.

Comment: Good to know for the future as well. Thanks again for sticking with me. I'm thrilled.

Comment: Rather than `do_shortcode`, I would strongly recommend applying the `the_content` filter: `apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content)` ...

Comment: I applied this directly into my page.php template as shown above - in place of the `do_shortcode` line - and it works just as well. May I ask why you're recommending this? Not doubting, just for my own understanding - thanks in advance.

Comment: This recommendation takes place because default `the_content` filter invokes `autoembed`, `wp_texturize`, `convert_smiles`, `wpautop`, `shortcode_unautop`, `prepend_attachment`, `wp_make_content_images_responsive`, `do_shortcode` filters, what is the normal processing sequence for WordPress post.

Answer (score 0):

See this code from a plugin that I am worked on, this was ages ago but you can see that the "do_shortcode()" function is included, try add it to your $output.

```
function rir_row( $params, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'rir-row'
    ), $params ) );
    $content = preg_replace( '/<br class="nc".\/>/', '', $content );
    $result = '<div class="' . $class . '">';
    $result .= do_shortcode( $content );
    $result .= '</div>';
    return force_balance_tags( $result );
}
add_shortcode('rir_row', 'rir_row');

function rir_item( $params, $content=null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'col-sm-1'
        ), $params ) );

    $result = '<div class="' . $class . '">';
    $result .= do_shortcode( $content );
    $result .= '</div>';
    return force_balance_tags( $result );
}
add_shortcode( 'rir_item', 'rir_item' );
```